# Is this googlebot or someone trying to impersonate googlebot?

Tags: security

On my elmah exceptions i keep getting exceptions of what appears to be googlebot but what I imagine is someone impersonating themselves trying to download what appears to be wares and other dodgy software from my server.

Here are just a few of the attempts and the software they are trying to get.

1. The controller for path '/download/msjavx86.exe' was not found
2. /downloads/IEZawGyiGtalkfont.EXE'
3. /downloads/alphazawgyiremover.exe
4. /downloads/gtalkmyanmaraddinremover.exe'
5. /cgi-bin/irbis32r/cgiirbis_32.exe
6. /ticker/MBISetup.exe'

The user agent and remote host are always the same

REMOTE_HOST 66.249.65.163

HTTP_USER_AGENT Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)

So my question is, is this googlebot searching for malware , or someone having a go at my server ??

Comment: What IP are they really coming from?  If it's from that IP, it's legit.

Comment: IP 66.249.65.163 = crawl-66-249-65-163.googlebot.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Yes. Google does scan websites for safe search listing. Malware scan Based on you server software is part of it.